# Post image to Amazon S3 like imagshack api using HTML

Tags: php, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cordova

I am developing an App where users can post photos. I have the app working well using Imageshack's API where basically all you have to do is write a HTML form with a post to imageshack and then it redirects the post to a page of your choice where I then use the received information to store a location of the image in my database.

My problem is I've heard bad things about Imageshack's reliability/scaleability and I want to move to Amazon's S3.

Is it possible to upload a photo to S3, then get a simple response with the location of the image that I can then store in my database via PHP?

Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, simple you can use file transfer method of phonegap

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
```

use your amazone bucket path for url.

if you need to upload larger files some times phonegap filetransfer may fail so you can write some native plugin (i tried video upload to amazone s3 and its succes )

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I could make it respond with the URL of the uploaded image with a POST or GET?

Comment: onprogress: Called with a ProgressEvent whenever a new chunk of data is transferred. (Function)